# Actionscript 3 filter using regex

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am trying to make a filter (user types in a string and I check the string against my list of names and only display names containing that string). I am having a lot of trouble with the regex and am either matching the whole string or pretty much none of the string.

**The idea is:**

```
var r:RegExp = new RegExp(filterRequest, "regex");
list.name.match(r);
```

**I have tried:**

```
var r:RegExp = new RegExp(filterRequest, "i"); //matches a-z and A-Z but no special ()*&^%$#@! characters
```

I have tried a combination of flags and escaping characters but none are working correctly. Any suggestions are appreciated - I also wouldn't mind a better explanation than the poor AS3 [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html). I am also reading [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f97.html) and have read [this](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html). Here is more character [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e91.html) in as3.

The biggest problem with `RegExp(filterRequest, "i");` is that it returns matches for `()` together where a string may be `hello (text)` but not `(` or `)` individually. It also matches `()*`, `$`, `^`, `\(` , `|`, and `.` but many of the names do not use any of these characters.

**Pattern Edit(s):**

```
"\S\s" // any character except white space and only white space (every character?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced each special character with an escaped version of itself to fix my problem. I did not escape `.` because it is useful in a filter to use as a wildcard any character match:

```
            filterRequest= filterRequest.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");
            filterRequest= filterRequest.replace(/\(/g, "\\(");
            filterRequest= filterRequest.replace(/\)/g, "\\)");
            filterRequest= filterRequest.replace(/\^/g, "\\^");
            filterRequest= filterRequest.replace(/\$/g, "\\$");
            filterRequest= filterRequest.replace(/\|/g, "\\|");
            filterRequest= filterRequest.replace(/\?/g, "\\|?");
            filterRequest= filterRequest.replace(/\*/g, "\\*");
            filterRequest= filterRequest.replace(/\+/g, "\\+");
            filterRequest= filterRequest.replace(/\[/g, "\\[");
            filterRequest= filterRequest.replace(/\{/g, "\\{");
```

Comment: I didn't understand what exactly you would like to do, but this is **awesome** tool that will help you every time when you deal with reg exp: http://www.regexr.com/ Long lives Grant Skinner! :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov RegExr was recently rewritten and no longer uses the Flash RegEx engine. May not be the best choice anymore, since JS-based RegEx (which it uses) has different things it can and cannot do compared to the engines found in AS3, PHP, etc. (such as JS not supporting certain lookarounds)

Comment: Hm, can you please specify some differences, as RegExp are commonly the same everywhere. I would love to know the differences, as I keep using it :)